# How to fix a memory leak caused by ListBox's _anchorItem field?

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, listbox

I have noticed that ListBox keeps a reference to a removed item in its private _anchorItem field.

The steps I perform are as follows.
I create a Window with a ListBox, and bind an ObeservableCollection with one item to that ListBox's ItemSource property. Then, after clicking the item in the window, I clear the ObeservableCollection programmatically.

At this point the ListBox is empty, but it's _anchorItem field still has a reference to the item I clicked on. How could I remove the reference programmatically?

The reason I need to remove the reference to the item is because it is a cause of a memory leak in my application.

Comment: Maybe you can try to set the listbox's ItemsSource to null, or please post some code to let us understand your problem!

Comment: Try setting the SelecteIndex = -1

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set the internal member through reflection. It know this is a hack but the memory issue was more problematic in the end.

```
        var propertyInfo = (typeof(ListBox)).GetProperty("AnchorItem", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);



        propertyInfo.SetValue(this, null, null);
```